# Magento 2.2 - Products showing out of stock

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory, quantity

I'm having an issue where only a handful of products are showing out of stock even though they have inventory and are set to in stock.

One thing I've noticed is that  the products will go to in-stock if I set the quantity to over 23. There is no Out-of-Stock threshold set and other products under 23 quantity are working.

I've compared this product to another product that is not having stock issues and there's no major differences.

I tried wiping all the categories, changing the weights, anything that could for some reason be throwing this off.

The site has been heavily modified, not by myself, is there anything in some of the template files that could be causing this. Any suggestions where to look or what else to do?

I've re-indexed the data, flushed the cache.

Comment: "The site has been heavily modified, not by myself, is there anything in some of the template files that could be causing this" anything can be possible. you will have to debug it

Comment: @PhilippSander , I should add that I'm not familiar with M2 so any direction on where to start looking would help a lot.

Comment: too hard to explain for me. use logs, enable DB logs and look at the queries. use xdebug